# Emulator option missing from Android studio IDE 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Upgraded my android studio to 4.1.2, and enabled the option "Launch in a tool window". still, I couldn't able to see the emulator menu in the sidebar.

`Android Studio 4.1.2 Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882, built on December 20, 2020 Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0 GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1237M Cores: 16 Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, Dart, io.flutter`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Issue solved after restarting the system :)

Comment: having the same issue for quite a while, and I have tried everything, can anyone help?

Comment: i have the same problem i make a post

Comment: Did you try restarting the pc? that's worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable this option from the Settings window (File -> Settings)

[image]

Comment: And do you have the option in View -> Tool Windows -> Emulator?

Comment: Actually, it is missing from there, already checked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this issue, this is how I've fixed it:

From the menu bar, go to View -> Tool Windows -> Emulator.